# Verify multiple state channel signatures in one transaction

Tags: contract-development, evm, signature, cryptography

What are some ways to verify multiple state channel signatures (using [ECverify](https://gist.github.com/axic/5b33912c6f61ae6fd96d6c4a47afde6d)) in a single transaction?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a method that accepts an array of signatures and an array of data hashes, and then have a for loop that runs ecverify with each signature and associated data.